# Grails - Multiple forms/Passing remote checkbox selections

Tags: grails, checkbox

I have a basic structure as such:

```
<g:form>
   actionSubmit
</g:form>

<g:form>
  actionSubmit
</g:form>


<g:each in personList - variable=person>
   <tr>
     <td><g:checkBox name="personList" value="${person.id}" checked="${false}"/></td>
     <td>
         <g:form>
            actionSubmit
         </g:form>
     </td>
   </tr>
</g:each>
```

Each of these forms relies on the personList checkbox array as a variable. The prior edition of my code wrapped the entire div in a form, which worked but caused problems when I added the third form in the table.

How can I pass the selected checkboxes? I have checkbox that selects all of the boxes - I just need to assign a variable/hiddenField with that array of selected boxes.

Thanks!

**Edit**

The issue with having a single form is that I have a column in each row has the ability to add elements to a one to many relationship. If I could pass the person.id with the corresponding action submit (so if I hit the actionSubmit on row 2, I want to pass person.id of row 2), then this is a piece of cake.

However, whenever I tried to tie the person ID, I end up with an array of ALL person IDs. So I figured the only way around this is to have separate forms.

```
                            <td>
                                <div id="reportsToResultsDiv2_${person.id}" class="reportsToResultsDiv2_${person.id}">
                                    <g:select id="reportsTo" name="reportsTo.id" from="${rtResults}" optionKey="id" value="" />
                                    <g:actionSubmit action="addReportsTo" value="Add" params="[c_id:'${person.id}']"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think checkbox supports both value and checked in that way.
Perhaps this is what you want?

```
<g:each in="${personList}" var="person>
    <g:form controller="person" action="doSomething">
        <g:hidden name="personId" value="${person.id}"/>
        <g:checkBox name="superFly" checked="${person.superFly}"/>
    </g:form>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Yeah - This is what I figured was the work around. Put for some odd reason PersonId is populated with all IDs, instead of THAT person instance's ID.

Comment: That is definitely strange.  If you look at the html source, are all the person ids present in the hidden element's value?

Answer (score 0):

Would a single form and several g:actionSubmit buttons work for you?

> Generates a submit button that maps to a specific action, which lets you have multiple submit buttons in a single form. - http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html

```
<g:form controller="book">
    <g:checkBox name="personList" value="${person.id}"/>
    <tr><td>
        <g:actionSubmit action="action1" value="firstButton"/>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <g:actionSubmit action="action2" value="secondButton"/>
    </td></tr>
</g:form>
```